# 2D elliptic gaussian beam on tilted wall

Tags: optics, laser, imaging

I can calculate laser's beam cross section at every point along z-axis. But how to do a "projection" of this beam on tilted wall? I see option to use ray tracing, but there is possibly a better way.

Ordinary projection using [Camera Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection) does not takes into account beam propagation till the wall (from first point of contact of the cross section, see figure). Are there some other types of projections?

[image: beam spot on tilted wall]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a coordinate transformation $x \rightarrow x', y \rightarrow y', z \rightarrow z'$ for a coordinate system in which the $x'y'$ plane is aligned with the wall.